# Should I use "compare to" or "compared to" in this case?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is correct?

1.

> The center of the small-town called Islip will develop **compared to** how it is in the present.

2. 

> The center of small-town called Islip will develop **compare to** how it is in the present.

Comment: I would hyphenate a phrase like *small town* only if using it as an adjective, as in *small-town ambience* = the ambience typical of small towns.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase should be "compared to".

It is defined here:
[Merriam-Webster "compared to"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compared%20to)
idiom:
in relation to (something else)
: measured or judged against (something else)

It is also discussed here:
[Collins "compared to"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/compared-with-something-compared-to-something)

The form "compare to" cannot be used that way. It can be used like this:
You can **compare** the future development **to** the present.